# Xamarin iOS handleAction never call

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have an Xamarin.Forms app where I want to use push notifications. I used azure push notification hub from mobile service to push the message. I want to create an interactive banner with some action "Action1" and "Action2" on iOS. I am able to receive the push message with "Action1" and "Action2" button. But tapping on that button does not do any thing. following is my code:

```cs
private static void RegisterPushAction()
{
    UIMutableUserNotificationAction acceptAction = new UIMutableUserNotificationAction ();
    acceptAction.Title = "Action1";
    acceptAction.Identifier = "ACCEPT_IDENTIFIER";
    acceptAction.ActivationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background;
    acceptAction.Destructive = false;
    acceptAction.AuthenticationRequired = false;

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction denyAction = new UIMutableUserNotificationAction ();
    denyAction.Title = "Action2;
    denyAction.Identifier = "DENY_IDENTIFIER";
    denyAction.ActivationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background;
    denyAction.Destructive = false;
    denyAction.AuthenticationRequired = false;

    UIMutableUserNotificationCategory acceptCategory = new UIMutableUserNotificationCategory ();
    acceptCategory.Identifier = "JOIN_CATEGORY";
    acceptCategory.SetActions (new UIUserNotificationAction[]{acceptAction,denyAction}, UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default);

    NSSet categories = new NSSet (acceptCategory);
    //iOS 7
    if (Convert.ToInt16 (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion.Split ('.') [0].ToString ()) < 8) {
        UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound;
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes (notificationTypes);
    } else {
        UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
        UIUserNotificationSettings settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes (types, categories);
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings (settings);
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications ();
    }   
}
```

To handle this I have following method:

```cs
public override void HandleAction (UIApplication application, string actionIdentifier, NSDictionary remoteNotificationInfo, Action completionHandler)
{
    if (actionIdentifier.Equals ("ACCEPT_IDENTIFIER")) {
        //var alert = notification.AlertBody;
        //new UIAlertView ("Msg", alert, null, "OK", null).Show ();
        //NotificationHelper.ReceivePushMessage (alert);
        ProcessNotification (remoteNotificationInfo, false);
    }
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    completionHandler ();
}
```

The above `HandleAction` method gets never called and it always calls `ReceivedRemoteNotification`

```cs
public override async void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
{
    ProcessNotification (userInfo, false);
}
```

I have different types of notificatiosn (e.g. a simple banner notification and a banner with Action)

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you still have the problem but you should try to write the function `HandleAction` like this:

```
public override void HandleAction (UIApplication application, String actionIdentifier, NSDictionary remoteNotificationInfo, NSDictionary responseInfo, Action completionHandler)
```

Let me know if it worked!